# What is the correct way to set locale on server?

Tags: server, language-support, locale, utf-8

On my development machine (a vagrant box with ubuntu) with a php application runnning I have one language with swedish: 
sv_SE.utf8

And I'm setting the locale with this function -

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'sv_SE');
```

And this works, but in production server it didn't. 
Consider those language settings in production:

```
sv_SE
sv_SE.iso88591
sv_SE.iso885915
sv_SE.utf8
swedish
```

When I changed it to

```
  setlocale(LC_ALL, 'sv_SE.utf8');
```

..it works. Somehow, the old code retrieves the wrong language, but when I changed it works. But is it correct way to configure the server with all the languages encodings? Wouldn't it be sufficient to just have *sv_SE.utf8* - language? Why would you want any else setting? 
Like *sv_SE.iso88591*. Seems weird to me.

Comment: How did you generate that list of locales? What does the terminal command `locale -a` output?

Comment: There were already a lot of languages installed already in the production server, but somehow when specified 'sv_SE' in the application it took the wrong language setting, not the utf-8 variant that I wanted.

Comment: (You didn't answer my questions.) If several similar locales are present on the production server, you apparently need to be specific. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Yes, apparently it maybe just chooses the first specified alphabetically. Maybe there is not so much more to it.